# Функция JavaScript для параметризации стринга

Tags: javascript

Ребята помогите мне плиз, хочу чтобы мой output был robin-singh-from-usa.
Пока, что мой output это массив ["robin", "singh", "from", "usa."]

```
 function string_parameterize(str1) {
  return str1.trim().toLowerCase().split(' ');
 }
 console.log(string_parameterize("Robin Singh from USA."));
```

Answer (score 2):

Осталось объединить полученный массив с помощью [функции `join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
function string_parameterize(str1) {
  return str1.trim().toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
}
console.log(string_parameterize("Robin Singh from USA."));
```